# Overloading implicit in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

full disclosure - this is for a homework assignment.  And I normally would not ask for homework help, but here it is.

I'm asked to provide 5 examples of "overloading implicit in c++".  I'm sure he is referring to operator overloading for types such as char, int, float, etc in iostream and the types themselves.

I understand explicitly overloading an operators such as (my dumb example)

```
class Vegetables {
    public:
        Vegetables();
        ~Vegetables();
        Vegetables& operator+ (Vegetables&);
        Vegetables& operator- (Vegetables&);
    private:
        int beans;
        ... // more veggies here
};

Vegetables& Vegetables::operator+ (Veggies&) {
    beans += Veggies.beans;
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

So I am just trying to decide if he is referring to the overloading that is "implicit" when adding types.  For example, int+double.  I think what actually occurs is int gets cast as a double, then the double + operator is used and a double is returned?  Of course, the way this happens varies based on if it is a value assignment or in iostream or other i/o method, etc.  But my point remains...

Comment: You should probably ask your instructor for clarification as to what he means by "overloading implicit."

Comment: Not a luxury I have right now.  I won't see him again till it is due and I didn't have a chance to look at the assignment before our last class.  I will ask before I turn it in, and just make him aware.

Comment: There is a possibility that your instructor means "overloading that is implicit in C++", like `+` being sort of conceptually overloaded for the various built-in types?

Comment: @Alf that is basically what I think as well.  As opposed to having to explicitly overload operators for a user-defined class.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you are looking for the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx)?  (since you mention the implicit conversions with the arithmetic operators)  [That link is from MSDN; you can find the same list many other places by searching for "usual arithmetic conversions."]

Comment: "I won't see him again till it is due" - maybe it can be clarified by email?

Comment: FWIW, I think it's important to separate conversions/promotions from overloading. I'd say conceptually `+` is overloaded for various types but the right hand and left hand sides must be the same. Any promotion happens before the operator. Though all this isn't specified in the Standard so it's arguable. So apart from binary operators (+, -, * etc) - there are others that are distinct in their syntax such as `?`, `[]`. I can think of more but want to clarify the type of answer he *might* be looking for, rather than providing it.

Comment: If you can't ask your professor, ask a classmate. If you and your classmate are both confused, it's easier to find a third classmate and more. If everyone is confused, then you don't need to do the assignment!

Comment: If everyone is confused, you decide as a group what it means, and everyone passes or everyone fails.  On a curve, either way, it doesn't matter...

Comment: @Tony: The standard does specify the conversions that can be performed before a function call or operator is called. Sections §4, §12.3, §13.3.3.

Comment: This might be stupid... but don't you have your professors email? This is something that you can easily ask by email, or go to his/her office for a 5 minute question.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I'm probably over-thinking this - it's trivial, but while §5 point 9 says "Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions", I can't see anything saying a compiler can't provide say `operator+(int16_t, int32_t)` and `operator+(int32_t, int16_t)`(say as an optimisation on a 16-bit machine, adding least-significant 16 bits then processing any carry), rather than doing a promotion for `operator+(int32, int32)`. So, while we think of 2 + 3.5 as necessitating 2's promotion, maybe the letter of the Standard's a little looser.

Comment: If you had *operator+(int16_t, int32_t)* and *operator+(int32_t, int16_t)*, your compiler would probably raise an issue with resolving "ambiguous overloading"...

Comment: @Mr.Ree: why? - conversions are only used if there's no exact match.

Comment: @Tony:  Interesting.  I have had problems with this under older compilers.  (It gave me a lot of grief at the time!)  But retesting under g++/gcc 3.4.4 & 4.0.1, using stdint.h & int8_t/int16_t/int32_t/int64_t/uint8_t/uint16_t/uint32_t/uint64_t shows **NO** current issues...  I stand corrected!

Comment: To update, I did email him, and he replied about an hour before class, which I didn't see.  Others questioned and from what I can tell, people were generally confused but took it to mean the operators that are already overloaded in c++ such as float+int, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.

It's late.  I'm tired.  But this is intriguing...

***"overloading implicit in c++"*** is far from clearcut.

This smacks of someone creating their own terminology.  Perhaps they are merely unable to view their own writings from a third-party perspective and are therefore being obtuse.  More than likely, your teacher is busy with his own research projects (or other work), and is doing the absolute minimum effort required to teach you.  It sucks.  You pay a lot of money and you're treated horribly.  I've been there myself.  All I can say is, get used to it.  Or find a better school.  And next time, read the homework ASAP, and ask your teacher!  If enough folks bother him, wasting his time, he'll get his act together.

**Next thought:**  Try google.  Always your friend.

**My thoughts:**  He may be talking about overloaded functions that are automatically (implicitly) created, such as the copy constructor.  Consider:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int i;
  Foo(int argI) : i(argI) { }
  //Foo( const Foo & argFoo ) : i(argFoo.i) { }
};

int
main()
{
  Foo f(2),g(3);
  Foo h = f;
}
```

With the copy constructor commented out, you will find only *f(2)* and *g(3)* invoke *Foo(int)*.  The *Foo h=f* line is correctly initializing *h* through an ***implicit copy constructor*** that overloads *Foo(int)*.  (Caveat Emptor:  I'm still stuck using the outdated gcc/g++ 3.4.4 & 4.0.1.  Your mileage with your compiler may vary...)

You might also get some mileage out of subclassing, as *copy constructors* and *operator=()* are not inherited, and new implicit versions are created.

**Another thought:**  As (everyone) has already mentioned, your instructor may be thinking of how types are converted.  For instance, we could initialize *g(3.2)* using a floating point value.  It would be converted to an int, and work with *Foo(int)*.  (Depending on your compiler settings, you might [should!] get a warning about loss of precision.)

We can go the other way too.  Adding a line to *class Foo* like:

```
operator int() { return i; }
```

Means we can now write:

```
cout << "Foo h = " << h << endl;
```

Wherein *h* is automatically converted to an int.

Automatic conversions can transpire between quite a number of built in types.  Between double/long-double/float and int/short/long/etc and  signed/unsigned and etc.  (Incidentally, that's a really good way to screw yourself up, by invoking the wrong overloaded function by mistake.  Converting -1 to unsigned makes for big numbers...  Accidentally doing unsigned math where you mean to do signed math is another easy gotcha!)

Pointers can be quietly converted to (void*).  Consider:

```
void voidFunction (void * v) { cout << "v= " << v << endl; }

int main() { Foo z(2); voidFunction(&z); }
```

Of course, the obvious case that everyone harps on is polymorphism, wherein we pass a derived class, and it's received as a base class.

There's another case wherein we pass data, and a new temporary object is created from that data for the invoked function/method.

There are variable-argument lists, that whole ellipsis thing (*printf(format,...)*).  (E.g. *#include <stdarg.h>.  va_start(), va_arg(), va_end().*)  Implicitly overloaded, but probably not what he was thinking about...

There are macros, both regular *#define FOO(X)* and variable-argument-list macros...  Again, clearly overloaded.  Again, probably not what he was thinking of...

There's templating, though that would seem to fall into the realm of explicit overloading...

**Bottom line:** Only your teacher knows what the hell he wants...  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement Val!  I was debating whether to even post it or not!